# how install php 5.4 apache 2.2 mysql from source on ubuntu

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, lamp

im use ubuntu 16 and im know at repository is not support php 5.4 again.
im tired use ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable becouse package is not exist
so how to install php 5.4 apache 2.2 mysql from source on ubuntu ?
becouse this project just work on php 5.4

Comment: Have you checked whether the `lsb_release -c` codename is compatible with the PPA repo?

Answer (score 0):

I just want to make you aware that PHP has reached it's EOL (End of Life) and no longer provide security updates or bugfixes which could be critical to your environment. If you need to run PHP 5.x, I'd suggest you looking at 5.6, or follow the migration guide.

**Have a look at:**
http://php.net/supported-versions.php

http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.php

### If you really want to to compile your own version

- Make sure you have a compiler and standard libraries available. `apt install build-essentials`
- Download each individual tarball for the AMP stack and install their dependencies.
- Blacklist any Apache, PHP packages etc in your dpkg/apt config.

Comment: yeah im know this version php 5.4 End of Life, but im need this.
im try this software cant run at php 5.6 becouse is many error in runtime but is work in php 5.4.
im try compile use make install, is work php 5.4 but apache2.2 is not detect my php installed

im realy confuse how i can any config
maybe u can make me tutorial manual install with compile webserver use php5.4.

thank u.

Comment: im use this metod

sudo -i
wget http://in1.php.net/distributions/php-5.xx.xx.tar.bz2
tar -xvf php-5.3.29.tar.bz2php-5.xx.xx.tar.bz2
cd php-5.xx.xx.tar.bz2
./configure
make
make install

but im i dont know next step how can make build webserver with this
(connect with apache2.2)

Comment: You need to install Apache first, have a look at http://howtolamp.com/lamp/httpd/2.4/installing/ and then follow up with http://howtolamp.com/lamp/php/5.5/installing/. To get the right libraries installed for php5-mysql I'd make sure to install it in the AMP order:

Apache - MySQL - PHP.